# Question regarding $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

If $ y = f(x) = x^2+1$ then the inverse of $f$  does not exist on $\mathbb R$.. But we can determine the value of $\frac{dx}{dy}$ at a non zero point c..It is because we can invert the function in a sufficiently small nbd around c..Am I correct?

Is it possible to invert any function whose  $\frac{dy}{dx}$ not equal to zero lin that way This is what I actually want to know...

Comment: You probably already know this, but given any curve in the plane (a function or not), the "inverse curve" is you rotating the sheet 90 degrees counterclockwise (the inverse curve may be a function or not). This is why there are a few theorems that say if you know the derivative of $f$ or the antiderivative of $f$, you know the derivative/antiderivative of inverse $f$, because there is really nothing that special about $f$ and it's inverse. They are basically the same. Therefore knowing stuff about 1 allows you to know stuff about the other. This picture goes away though for multivariable

Comment: So if you have a non-zero tangent line placed on your curve, when you rotate the sheet of paper 90 degrees counterclockwise. A tangent line will still be there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. What you are referring to is the [Inverse Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem). It says that if $f$ is differentiable and $f'$ is continuous and $f'(c) \ne 0$, then there is a neighbourhood $U$ around $c$ such that $f \colon U \to f(U)$ is invertible.

A cousin of the Inverse Function Theorem is the [Implicit Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) which gives similar conditions for when you can solve an equation for one of the variables. E.g. solving $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ for $y = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ near a point such as $(3/5,4/5)$.

Comment: So u are saying if $ f ^'$ is not continuous then $dx/dy$ may not exist at a point c where $dy/dx$ is non zero..@Trevor Gunn

Comment: So we can not find the value of $\frac{dx}{dy}$ at origin of the following function $y =f(x)=\begin{cases}x+x^2\sin\frac1{x^2}&\text{if }x\ne 0\\ 0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$. But $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is $1$.  @Trevor Gunn

Comment: @cmi When I say that $f$ is differentiable, I mean at every point. But just because the derivative exists at every point does not mean the derivative is a continuous function. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_classes

Comment: [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3364607/does-fracdxdy-at-0-exist-and-fracdydx-fracdxdy-at-0-is-1 ] Can you please check this question once and kindly answer it? This question is related to this question.. I think if I can get the answer of that question , my doubt will be cleared..@Trevor Gunn

Comment: if $f$ is differentiable and $f'$ is **not** continuous and $f'(c) \ne 0$, then there is a neighbourhood $U$ around $c$ such that $f \colon U \to f(U)$ is invertible.  Is the statement correct? If it is false , Can you give a counter example?@Trevor Gunn

Comment: While the Inverse Function Theorem is most often stated for continuously differentiable functions, it remains true for everywhere (but not necessarily continuously) differentiable functions. See https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/09/12/the-inverse-function-theorem-for-everywhere-differentiable-maps/ @cmi

Comment: $$y =f(x)=\begin{cases}x+x^2\sin\frac1{x^2}&\text{if }x\ne 0\\ 0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$$                                  This function is everywhere differentiable but you can not get a nbd around the origin where the function will possess an inverse...!!@Trevor Gunn

Comment: @cmi continuity implies that if $f'(c) \ne 0$ then $f'$ is nonzero in a neighbourhood of $c$. If $f'$ is not continuous, then you need to add that assumption.

Comment: That's what I asked you. What will happen when f^' is not continuous in the Inverse Function theorem?However I have got my answer. Thank you for showing me the way. @Trevor Gunn

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3364607/does-fracdxdy-at-0-exist-and-fracdydx-fracdxdy-at-0-is-1 Can you please check this question once and kindly answer it? This question is related to this question.. I think if I can get the answer of that question , my doubt will be cleared..@Trevor Gunn

Comment: @cmi I'm sorry, I don't have time to answer that question. I think the answer that is already there is reasonable and you can also read Terry Tao's blog post.