# Does $\frac{dx}{dy}$ at $0$ exist and $\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy}$ at $0$ is $1$ for the following function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

$$y =f(x)=\begin{cases}x+x^2\sin\frac1{x^2}&\text{if }x\ne 0\\ 0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases}$$

We can see $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ at $0$ is $1$. My question:

> **Does $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$ at $0$ exist and $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ . $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$ at $0$ is $1$**?

If not then  is it because $f$ can not be invertible in any nbd around the point $0$ ?

Actually  I was trying to understand when $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$ at a point exists and $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ . $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$ at that point is $1$ if $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ at that point exists.

Can anyone please help me to clear  my doubt?

Comment: A heuristic way to see that *if* $dx/dy$ does exist, then it has to be $1$ is to think of the derivative as the slope of the graph of the function at that point. If we invert a function with unit slope at the origin, then near the origin it approximately doesn't change, so it still has the same slope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, for $dx/dy$ to exist at some point, we must have that $dy/dx>0$ or strictly negative at that point. However, this is not sufficient, since we need the function to be invertible in a *neighborhood* of this point; this happens if $dy/dx$ maintains its sign in a neighborhood of this point. Also, one can see that if $dy/dx$ does *not* maintain the same sign in a neighborhood of this point, then it cannot be strictly monotonic there.

Thus, *what we need is that $f'$ have the same sign in a neighborhood of the point of concern.*

To have this happen, it is sufficient that $f$ be continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of the point of interest; however, this is clearly too restrictive. Indeed, one sees that even if $f'$ is discontinuous at the point of concern but has a limiting value (possibly infinite), all we need require is that the limiting value have the same sign as the value of the derivative at the point in question. We may say more -- even if there is no limiting value, so long as the discontinuity is of the first kind (i.e., a jump), then again as long as the half-limits have the same sign as the derivative at the point in question, then all would still be well. Indeed, if either or both of the half-limits fails or fail to exist, then this is still doable provided that there is some neighborhood of the point where the derivative is of the same sign.

In these cases the derivative of the inverse is given by $$\frac{1}{dy/dx}.$$ To see the latter, since we have that $y=f(x)$ and $g=f^{-1}$ exists, then we may solve for $x$ to get $x=g(y).$ Now differentiating $y=f(x)$ with respect to $y$ gives $$dy/dy=\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\frac{dx}{dy},$$ or $$1=\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{dx}{dy},$$ and the result follows.

On the other hand, for some derivatives discontinuous at the point in question, they may change sign in every neighborhood of the point; then one can see that in such cases it is *impossible* to have an inverse mapping.

So, the function defined in OP, while having positive derivative at the origin, fails to have a *continuous* derivative near the origin, since for $x\ne 0,$ the derivative is given by $$1+2x\sin\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac2x\cos\frac{1}{x^2},$$ which has no limiting value at the origin. But we have seen that this is not perforce an issue. However, here, we see that the derivative oscillates between positive and negative values near the origin, and simultaneously becomes unbounded. Thus, it is not strictly monotonic in any interval about $x=0,$ and therefore cannot be invertible there. It follows that we cannot unambiguously calculate $dx/dy$ at that place.

Comment: How do you say that the function is invertible in a nbd around c if $dy/dx >0$ ? In my case  $dy/dx =1 $at the origin..But the function is not invertible in any nbd around the origin..@Allawonder

Comment: @sani I now see your point clearly (yours is a good question, contrary to first impression). I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I will check your editing and let you know if any problem @Allawonder

Comment: So you are basically saying that we can not unambiguously calculate $\frac{dx}{dy}$..Right?@Allawonder

Comment: But I am concerned about the existence? @Allawonder

Comment: If a high school student is asked to find $\frac{dx}{dy}$ at the point $0$ ,he will tell you the answer is 1.. Then what would you tell him? @Allawonder

Comment: @sani I would ask the high-schooler to see their calculation, and find the flaw.

Comment: No, we cannot unambiguously calculate $dx/dy.$ Yes, existence of *what*? Recall that we only defined derivatives for *functions.* What function has the derivative $dx/dy$? The only way to escape this is instead to think geometrically, and talk of finding the slopes of curves, instead of derivatives of functions.